# Intel Backport driver crashes the system completely

Tags: intel, 19.10, iwlwifi

I upgraded my Kubuntu 19.10 to 5.3.0-26-generic on a Lenovo ThinkPad and as far as I remember the driver-manager popped up to tell me, that there is a driver for Intel iwlwifi.

After selecting this driver and turning Wifi on, the machine crashes and freezes completely. I turned Wifi off globally now.

```
$ubuntu-drivers devices
== /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.1/0000:03:00.0 ==
modalias : pci:v00008086d0000095Bsv00008086sd00005210bc02sc80i00
vendor   : Intel Corporation
model    : Wireless 7265 (Dual Band Wireless-AC 7265)
driver   : backport-iwlwifi-dkms - distro free
```

The Driver Manager in the Hardware section in the Settings freezes now while "Collecting information about your system"

How can I fix this, to use Wifi again?
Thanks so far...

Comment: Why did you install backport-iwlwifi-dkms? Ubuntu 19.10 should drive any Intel 7265 without. Did you see it under 'Additional Drivers' and install it? Wasn't your wireless working well before you installed it? Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: @chili555 Yes, sure, you are right! "Never change a running system."
But the Kubuntu Driver Manager gave me the impression, that it could be a good idea to install it.

I now did an ```apt purge backport-iwlwifi-dkms``` and everything is running again.

Comment: Please post this an an answer so the searchers will find the solution and so I can upvote it!

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by switching to a tty (Ctrl - Alt - F2) and then doing a

```
sudo apt purge backport-iwlwifi-dkms
```